# How to get inheritance to work in my model layer?

Tags: playframework

I know that you should extend `Model` to get all the jpa functionality. However, java does not allow multiple inheritance... Therefore, I would like to know how to architect in play the following design:

```
public class Person extends Model {
}

// should be able to extend Person
public class Doctor extends Model {
}

// should be able to extend Person     
public class Patient extends Model {
}

public class Item extends Model {
    // Doens't matter whether it's a Doctor or a Patient
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Person> owners;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Doctor and Patient objects should inherit from Person. Java does not allow multiple inheritance but you can extend children objects with Person which inherits model already.

```
public class Person extends Model {
}

public class Doctor extends Person {
}

public class Patient extends Person{
}

public class Item extends Model {
    @ManyToMany
    public List owners;
}
```

What you cannot do in Java is:

```
public class Doctor extends Person, Model {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the way Java deals with inheritance. I wasn't sure about how Play would deal with that. Extending Model in a superclass and later extending that superclass worked like a charm. I'm a JPA user and I'm learning how to let play encapsulate it all for me. Sometimes I want to see what's going on. But I must admit that play does a wonderful job and I'm really enjoying it =)